# Best practice to provide synchronous function call and asynchronous inner code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular-promise, synchronous, es6-promise

I want to offer a synchronous helper function in `JavaScript` that returns a simple string. Inside that function I have to query a SQLite database, which works with promises.
What's the recommended way to synchronize async calls?

```
function getToken() {
    console.debug("getToken called");

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var db = sql.getDb();
    db.executeSql('SELECT token from system LIMIT 1', [],
        function(result) {
            if (result.rows.length === 0 || !isTokenFormatValid(result.rows[0].token)) {
                deferred.resolve('');
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(result.rows[0].token);
            }
        }, function(error) {
            console.error();
            deferred.reject(Error('SQL: Not able to query token in system table. ' + error));
        });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Helper function:

```
function getTokenHelper() {
    // Todo: return token synchronously
}
```

The processing order is more complex but simplified in this post. Unfortunately I need a synchronous return value because the consumer is not able to handle promises.

Comment: You _can't_ return a result from a asynchronous function, synchronously.

Comment: use callback function

Comment: *"Unfortunately I need a synchronous return value because the consumer is not able to handle promises."* - Not really, you just need to invoke the synchronous consumer in the callback of the promise. Whether you say `promise.then(syncFunction)` where `syncFunction` is your function that doesn't take a promise, but a value, it should work without any problem.

Comment: Why you want a synchronous function when you are using AngularJS? All the pain of asynchronous functions is borne by AngularJS. You just need to make sure that you are resolving / rejecting promises properly. Rejection is very useful when you have higher priority for handling user interaction than waiting for promise to be resolved by some asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thank you guys. I reorganized my code to deal with async. Question could be closed. And also thanks for linking to the similar question, which has very good explanations.